# Is there any current imagery of Mars2020?

Tags: mars, perseverance

Are there any current photos or video from the Mars2020 spacecraft, or since the first burn?  It would be cool to check on this daily/weekly.

Comment: There's nothing to take a picture with. The lander and the helicopter are between the heat shield and back shell, and will remain there until the vehicle reaches Mars.

Comment: Well, there was video of the launch and first burn.  Was this only from the rocket stage?

Comment: @Mike yes, these views were from the Atlas rocket. Live-stream cameras are useful during a launch for engineering analysis of the very-visual processes going on. Running live-stream cameras on space probes that are not meant for that purpose serves pretty much only as a PR benefit, and there's not much to see anyway.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there's nothing to take a picture with.

Comment: **voting to LEAVE OPEN** because this question can be answered, see for example [NASA asteroid camera spots China's Tianwen-1 Mars spacecraft speeding away from Earth](https://www.space.com/china-mars-tianwen-1-spacecraft-nasa-photo.html) and also [When was the last time that Starman/Roadster was seen?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/29921/12102) I think there's more to be learned by allowing answers to be posted than by blocking others from a chance to post an answer.